# Group by sku, max date SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, greatest-n-per-group

I know this is asked quite a bit here, and I have tried to use other examples to incorporate into my own, but I can't seem to make this work.

I have columns for sku, date, and cost, and I want to view all 3 columns, but only by max date, grouped by sku.
Currently:

```
Sku   Date     Cost
1     06/24/15 .01
1     02/22/14 .02
2     06/24/15 .04
2     02/22/14 .05
```

Need:

```
Sku   Date     Cost
1     06/24/15 .01
2     06/24/15 .04
```

This is what my SQL looks like:

```
SELECT dbo_SKU.PROD_CODE AS Sku, dbo_LOTS.REC_DATE AS [Last Date], 
   dbo_LOT_ITEM.COST AS Cost
FROM (dbo_LOTS INNER JOIN dbo_SKU ON dbo_LOTS.SKU_ID = dbo_SKU.SKU_ID) 
INNER JOIN dbo_LOT_ITEM ON dbo_LOTS.LOT_ID = dbo_LOT_ITEM.LOT_ID;
```

Here is what the design view looks like (I'm more of a visual person):
[Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEpob.jpg)

This is week 2 of teaching myself how to operate Access and how it all works, so if we could break this down in crayon on how I make this work correctly, that would be great.

Comment: removed   improper tag  mysql

Comment: Since you're more visual, click on the Totals button while in design view and play around with the query. You'll be able to do a lot of things with that enabled; Group by, sum, min, max, etc...

Comment: what will be if max date appear multiple time?

Comment: I don't think the date can ever be the same, since these dates are lot receive dates.

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas on how to achieve this? Could I use a crosstab to accomplish this somehow? I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add additional logic to get the last date.  One method is to add a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT s.PROD_CODE AS Sku, l.REC_DATE AS [Last Date],  li.COST AS Cost
FROM (dbo_LOTS as l INNER JOIN
      dbo_SKU as si
      ON l.SKU_ID = s.SKU_ID
     ) INNER JOIN
     dbo_LOT_ITEM as li
     ON l.LOT_ID = li.LOT_ID
WHERE l.REC_DATE = (SELECT MAX(l2.REC_DATE)
                    FROM dbo_LOTS as l2
                    WHERE l2.SKU_ID = l.SKU_ID
                   );
```

Comment: Thanks, could we go through this a little bit so I have a better understanding? what is l and l2? Where is l2 coming from? I assume this is a label or an alias? Is it possible to do this without an alias so that I understand exactly what is taking place? (sorry for being difficult)

Comment: Here is what I tried using yours as a template and it crashed access: SELECT dbo_SKU.PROD_CODE AS Sku, dbo_LOTS.REC_DATE AS [Last Date], dbo_LOT_ITEM.COST AS Cost FROM (dbo_LOTS INNER JOIN dbo_SKU ON dbo_LOTS.SKU_ID = dbo_SKU.SKU_ID)WHERE dbo_LOTS.REC_DATE = (SELECT MAX(l2.REC_DATE) FROM dbo_LOTS as l2 WHERE l2.SKU_ID = dbo_LOTS.SKU_ID);

Comment: @Charles . . . You probably need an index on `dbo_LOTS(SKU_ID, REC_DATE)`.

Comment: They are linked dbo tables, is it possible to index them?

Comment: So I combined the query to make things a little bit more simple, and tried the following query, but only receive 1 record, which seems to be the newest record. SELECT LotDateAndCost.Sku, LotDateAndCost.[Last Date], LotDateAndCost.Cost
FROM LotDateAndCost
WHERE LotDateAndCost.[Last Date] = (SELECT MAX(l2.[Last Date]) 
FROM LotDateAndCost  as l2
WHERE l2.Sku = LotDateAndCost.Sku);

Comment: Any more thoughts on this? I have been working on this for a week and just can't seem to make it work correctly.

Comment: @Charles . . . This query would be much easier to write in SQL Server.  MS Access is only hindering you.

Comment: I've just put so much work into creating this database. This is a small part of a very large project that has all been created in access, I'm not sure where I would even start with SQL server. I've got custom tables built, queries, unions, linked to excel spreadsheets with macro's and all kinds of other things. If there is a way to incorporate this into my current setup I would be open to the idea.

Comment: Not really sure how but I got it to work without crashing. Now trying to combine it with my main query has become the problem, saying that the parameter cannot be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
SELECT dbo_SKU.PROD_CODE AS Sku, dbo_LOTS.REC_DATE AS [Last Date], dbo_LOTS.COSTPERSKU AS Cost
FROM dbo_LOTS INNER JOIN dbo_SKU ON dbo_LOTS.SKU_ID = dbo_SKU.SKU_ID
WHERE (((dbo_LOTS.REC_DATE)=(SELECT MAX(l2.REC_DATE) 

FROM dbo_LOTS as l2 WHERE l2.SKU_ID = dbo_LOTS.SKU_ID)));
```